# Regex: how to use lookahead/lookbehind on the result of a pattern?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to learn more about regex today.

I'm simply trying to match an order number not surrounded by brackets (`#1234` but not `[#1234]`) but my question is more in general about using lookahead assertions on an arbitrary pattern.

On my first attempts I noticed my negative lookahead match `\d+(?!\])` would cause the `\d+` to keep matching digits until it wasn't followed by a `]`. I need the digits to match only if their entirety isn't followed by a `]`.

My current solution kills the match at the first digit by looking ahead to see if there's a `]` in the digit chain.

Is this a standard way to go about this? I'm just repeating the match pattern in the lookahead. If this were a more complex regex, would I approach it the same? Repeat the valid match followed by the invalid match and have the regex engine repeat itself for every letter?

For valid matches, it would have to match itself as many times as the characters in the match.

```
(?<!\[) # not preceded by [
#\d+ 
(?!\d*\]) # not followed zero+ digits and ] 

# or (?!\d|\]) # not followed by digit or ]
```

I'd appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "...  only if their entirety isn't followed by a ]". Can you add an example of a string that isn't getting the match you want, and what the match should be in that case?

Comment: @Faust: I'm getting the match I want, I just think my method isn't any good. Narendra Yadala pointed out what I needed exactly to prevent backtracking. Thanks all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using a possessive quantifier along with lookarounds like this

```
(?<!\[)#\d++(?!\])
```

The problem in your case is when you use `\d+` it allows backtracking and ends up having a partial match `#123`. Once you change that to possessive quantifier, it will not backtrack and only match if the sequence of digits is not preceded/followed by brackets.

[Live Demo](http://regexr.com/2v7us)

**Edit**
If possessive quantifiers are not supported then you can use this one

```
#\d(?<!\[#\d)(?!\d*\])\d*
```

Comment: Brilliant!  `Unlike a greedy quantifier, it will not give up matches as the engine backtracks. With a possessive quantifier, the deal is all or nothing. ` That's exactly what I needed. I'm glad I asked the question : ) I'll accept as soon as I can.

Comment: Ouch, just found out python re doesn't support it... Will probably use my original function then :(

Comment: @YujiTomita Added a regex which will work when the possessive quantifiers are not supported.

Comment: thanks for the edit. That's a better approach since it only checks the lookahead once on the first digit. I like it!